# A convergence problem： splitting a double sum

Tags: sequences-and-series, number-theory, summation, analytic-number-theory

I have been facing some difficulties with the following question.

> For an absolutely convergent series $\sum_m a_m$, and the Möbius function $\mu(n)$, $x=(x_1,x_2)\in \mathbb{R}^2$, and $\alpha ,c\in \mathbb{R}$, if we have the following double sum $$\mathcal{S}=\sum_{m\in \mathbb{Z}^2}a_m\sum_{n\le N}\mu(n)e(m_1(x_1+n\alpha)+m_2(ncx_1+x_2)),$$
>   assuming that the inside is $o_{m_1,~m_2}(N)$, which means the constant may depend on $m_1,m_2$. Do we still have $\mathcal{S}=o(N)?$ How do we separate the $m$-terms from the inside?

Any comment is welcome! Thanks in advance!

Comment: What is the $e$ function? $exp$? If so, look up "exponential sums". Also, your parentheses are unbalanced.

Comment: $x_1$ and $\alpha$ and $c$ and $x_2$ are what? arbitrary real numbers?

Comment: @martycohen Oh, yes. Thanks for the correction. $e(x):=e^{2\pi ix}$, which is a standard abrreviation in number theory.

Comment: @GerryMyerson Yes. Sorry I didn't make it clear. Actually my problem lies in whether we can separate the outer sum from the inside while the inside is still relevant to $m_1$ and $m_2$.

Comment: @Gerry Myerson My trouble here is that Abel's summation formula is invalid if the constant depends on $m_1$ and $m_2$ exponentially. Need another way to handle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With a help from MathOverflow, I found this reference, 
http://qjmath.oxfordjournals.org/content/os-8/1/313.full.pdf

which contains this result(Theorem1 in the paper):

For any given $K>0$, 
$$\sum_{n\leq x} \mu(n) e(n\theta) = O\left(\frac{x}{(\log x)^K}\right),$$
uniformly in $\theta$.

The result $S=o(N)$ is straightforward from there. Actually stronger result holds, 
$$S=O\left(\frac{N}{(\log N)^K}\right).$$

Indeed, 
$$
|\mathcal{S}|\leq \sum_{m\in \mathbb{Z}^2}|a_m| \left|\sum_{n\le N}\mu(n)e(m_1(x_1+n\alpha)+m_2(ncx_1+x_2))\right|$$
$$
= \sum_{m\in \mathbb{Z}^2}|a_m| |e(m_1x_1+m_2x_2)| \left|\sum_{n\le N}\mu(n)e(m_1n\alpha+m_2ncx_2)\right|
$$
$$
= \sum_{m\in \mathbb{Z}^2}|a_m|  \left|\sum_{n\le N}\mu(n)e(n(m_1\alpha+m_2cx_2))\right|
$$
$$
\leq \sum_{m\in \mathbb{Z}^2}|a_m| \frac{N}{(\log N)^K}
$$
and the result follows by the absolute convergence of $a_m$.

(Note that $e(x+y)=e(x)e(y)$. )

Comment: Thanks for your help, though I don't think this will work, since we still have terms involving $m_1$ and $m_2$ in the sum outside. Actually this problem comes from a recent paper (http://arxiv.org/abs/1303.4957) by Jianya Liu and Peter Sarnak. In their case, they encountered a much more complicated exponential sum involving double exponential functions, which Davenport or anyone else had not handled.

Comment: The above work uniformly in $\theta$. So $\sum_{n\leq x}\mu(n)e(n(m_1\alpha+cm_2x_2))$ is uniformly bounded by $\frac{N}{(\log N)^K}$.

Comment: Yeah but what about the other terms? They are all relevant to $m_1,m_2$.

Comment: I will put details in my answer.

Comment: Thanks for the help! Could you be kindly enough to send Davenport's paper to me(qiangzhangsdu@gmail.com)? It's releally a pitty I have no access to the article.

Comment: You're welcome. I sent the paper. For the access to the article, you might want to try logging in to your school's library website and try the link again.