# Asymptotics for the Alternating Mertens Function

Tags: number-theory, asymptotics

Are there any tight bounds, or any nontrivial ones actually, known for, with the lack of a better name, the Alternating Mertens Function:
$$
S(n) = \sum_{k=1}^{n} \left((-1)^k \mu\left(k \right)\right)
$$

**Edit:**

Thanks to i707107. As stated in the answer here, [A convergence problem： splitting a double sum](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/332832/a-convergence-problem-splitting-a-double-sum/350510#350510) , this sum has a more general asymptotic as:
$$
S_\theta(n) = \sum_{k=1}^{n} \left(e^\left(2 \pi i \theta k \right) \mu\left(k \right)\right)
$$

For which, $ S(n) $ is just a special case where $ \theta = \frac{1}{2} $. It turns out due to a result by H. Davenport that $ S_\theta(n) $ is $ O(x/\ln^\mathcal{E}(x)) $ for all real $ \theta$ and all $ \mathcal{E} > 0 $.

My question is for a more improved bound though, as this bound is not too much greater thank that of $ O(x) $.

Comment: This doesn't have the answer to your question, but I thought it might interest you: http://oeis.org/A247418

Comment: The sum I had was the negative of that, so it would imply for at least small values it tends to be somewhat regular. I really have no idea how it might diverge though. I assume it will, but as to what rate, I have no idea.

Comment: See this: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/332832/a-convergence-problem-splitting-a-double-sum/350510#350510

Comment: So, for any $K>0$, it is bounded above by $n/(\log n)^K$.

Comment: the asymtotics of $\sum_{n < x} \mu(n) e^{2 i \pi n a}$ is connected to the equivalent of the prime number theorem for Dirichlet L-functions : $L(s,\chi) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \chi(n) n^{-s}$ and $\frac{1}{L(s,\chi)} = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \chi(n) \mu(n) n^{-s}$. As for $\zeta(s)$, you prove $L(s,\chi)$ has no zero on $Re(s)=1$, and then you write $\sum_{n < x} \chi(n) \mu(n)$ as a contour integral, and you show it is $o(x)$ ($\mathcal{O}(x^{1/2+\epsilon})$ if RH was true). Finally, because of the discrete Fourier transform : $e^{2 i \pi n a} = \sum_{\chi} c(\chi,a) \chi(n)$ and voila